# Using awk in shellscript with parameters?

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sh

because i haven't found a solution on google or the searchfunction i will ask here.

Here is my code :

```
Send="last -n 1 $1 | awk '{ print $1 " " $2  }'"
```

My problem is, that my shell script is using parameters.

When i'm calling my script:

```
myScript hello world
```

Then my awk-Command looks like

```
awk '{ print hello " " world }'
```

But how could I avoid this? is there a way?

Because this is a part of a project, i couldn't post more code. ;/

Comment: What do you do with your `$Send` variable?

Comment: This is for the identification of a user, don't to send duplicate messages ;)
Maybe the name is a bit confuse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. first change the outer "'s to `$()` so:   `send=$(last -n 1 $1 | awk '{print $1 " " $2}')`
2. use the `FS` (field separator) variable which defaults to space in awk instead of " " for a space so: `send=$(last -n 1 $1 | awk '{print $1 FS $2}')`

Comment: Replace `FS` with `,` as that's the purpose of OFS.

Comment: both work. an argument can be made that , is less to type when compared to `FS`, but my preference is for `FS`.  As it helps me logically make the distinction, whereas a comma can be easily overlooked. Especially when reviewing older code. Preference really.

Comment: If you prefer `$1 FS $2` to `$1, $2`, I would argue that you ought to use `$1 OFS $2`.

Comment: @EdMorton and @WilliamPursell, I politely disagree on `OFS` or , Over `FS`. That would work well for this case, where `OFS` or ',' would input a space, but I use `FS` explicitly as the field separator. I make mention of that in my answer. so if it was changed  such as: `awk -F- '{print $1 OFS $2}'` you would not get the same as if you used `FS`. If you want space, use a comma, but `FS` is more robust in this case.

Comment: (cannot edit the above) -- There are cases where you may want to use the `OFS`, and those are when you are setting the Output Field Separator explicitly to something other then the `FS`, but sometimes you just want to remove or transpose a col using `awk`, it is a bit superfluous to set the `OFS` when using the `FS` is sufficient. Which, brings me back to this being a matter of preference. My answer indicated `FS` was being used as the Field Separator.